# devtools::check_rhub(): N checking CRAN incoming feasibility

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran

after I done `devtools::check_rhub()`

It show the **note** that:

```
checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
  Maintainer: 'Name <email@address>'
  
  New submission
  
  License components with restrictions and base license permitting such:
    GPL-3+ file LICENSE
  File 'LICENSE':
                        GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
                           Version 3, 29 June 2007
(continue with very long license file )
```

I wonder if there is anything I need to change to my **Description** file to eliminate the **note**

So, far, what I write for licence is. But the **note** will comes out with the context of the whole license.

```
License: GPL-3+ file LICENSE
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you including the `file LICENSE` part if you don't want to specify restrictions? Are you opposed to simply specifying `License: GPL (>= 3)`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there a big difference between using ```License: GPL (>= 3)``` and ```License: GPL -3```? As they told me using ```License: GPL -3```, I think it maynot be good to change to  ```License: GPL (>= 3)``` . But if it does not matter, I can consider change it.

Comment: `GPL (>= 3)` licenses the software under GPL-3 and later versions. If you prefer, you can of course use `GPL-3` only as the license. The point is that you should omit the `+ file` part (if you don't intend to specify additional restrictions in a file).